# How to type a variable to a module in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given files

Path\Example.ts:

```
export module Example {
    ... Stuff ...
}
```

and Test.ts:

```
import { Example }    from "Path/Example";

let exampleMock = getExampleMock(); // getExampleMock returns an any that matches the type structure of Example

let e = exampleMock as Example; // Errors: Cannot find name 'Example'
let local = Example; // local is typed as Example;
local = exampleMock ; // since exampleMock is an any, compiler allows this call.

... use local with full typing of Example module
```

Is there any way to type a variable to a module, without setting it to the real module first?

Comment: semi-related: I would really suggest moving away from "internal modules" if possible.  According to your code you already use real modules, so I think it should be possible for you...

Comment: @st_huck, you mean how my Test.ts code isn't wrapped in a module?  My Example.ts is exporting the module, so that would be an external module correct?

Comment: I meant I didn't understand why you use 'module' keyword in your Example.ts. Maybe it's intentional, just wanted to comment if it's not.
Indeed, your example.ts in considered an external module, but what it exports is an internal module. You have no reason to use an internal module, because all your local variables in example.ts will still be private to the file, since it's an external module. maybe I'm the one missing something here?
why not simply `export const Example = {...}`?

Comment: @st_huck I'm using Require JS to load my files, so I have to have everything that i want to import, defined in an module.  My Test.ts in practice would be in a module as well, but it wasn't important to what i was  doing.  Does that answer the question?  Maybe I need to brush up on internal modules...  I just assumed that was dropping the `export` keyword from module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
let exampleMock = getExampleMock() as typeof Example;
```